# How to get the sum of values in a table interval?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The question is very simple :-). I'm a beginner.

tables

```
Declare @startDate date,
Declare @endDate date

Select
d.ID,
d.Date as DateDocumet,
dt.id As TypeDocument,
p.Name as ProductName,
p.Price as Price,
d.qty

from Documents d
LEFT  join product p on d.ProductId = p.id  
LEFT  join DocumentType dt on d.DocumentTypeId = dt.id
```

Result:
[image]

A task…..
There are two date variables.

How to get the sum of values(qty) between dates(@startDate - @endDate).

How to get the sum of values(qty) up to @startDate.

How get the sum of values(qty) down to @endDate.

If DocumentType is 1. Then the value(qty) minus.

Comment: Up to and down to is exclusive or inclusive? And what does `If DocumentType is 1. Then the value(qty) minus.` mean?

Comment: Example.
TypeDocument   qty
1                            100
2                             200
2                             300
Sum (200+300-100)

Comment: Do you mean that when summing, subtract the quantity instead of adding if DocumentType = 1? And are the dates inclusive or exclusive?

Comment: "Вы имеете в виду, что при суммировании вычитайте количество вместо добавления, если DocumentType = 1" Yes)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need conditional aggregation `SUM(CASE WHEN...`.

`CROSS APPLY` also makes it easier to pre-calculate the negative `qty`

```sql
Declare @startDate date;
Declare @endDate date;

Select
   SUM(CASE WHEN d.Date < @startDate THEN QtyToSum END),
   SUM(CASE WHEN d.Date >= @startDate AND d.Date < @endDate THEN QtyToSum END),
   SUM(CASE WHEN d.Date >= @endDate THEN QtyToSum END),
from Documents d
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CASE WHEN d.DocumentTypeId = 1 THEN -d.qty ELSE d.qty END) ) AS v(QtyToSum)
```